# Potential bug in rep change badge?

Tags: support, bug

Okay, so this may just be a bug or some issue with my cache, but I noticed some errant behavior of the rep change indicator in the top bar.  And it happens both here in meta and on Ask Ubuntu.

This is what it is at the beginning of *every single page* once it's first loaded:
[image: Initial State]

This is what it shows after I've looked at it and clicked out:

[image: After Reviewing and Clicking Outside the Popup Window]

**However**, it returns to the initial image state there whenever I reload the page or navigate away.  Is this a bug in the system, or do I just need to go nuking my browser cache and start it over?

Comment: Yeah, [it's a known issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268957/topbar-notifications-dont-go-away) all over the SE network.

Comment: Am also suffering this  ut as mentioned by oli it is being worked on.